# Summary of unknown amounts of integers in a list

Tags: python

How can I transfer the list that I take from the user as unknown amount of integers?

```
f.sum(i[0],i[-1])        

def sum(*args):
    total=0
    for a in args:
        total+=a
        if a is "q":
            break
    print(total)

while True:
    print("sum")
    y = input("Number: ")
    if int(y) is 0:
        print(i)
        f.sum(i[0],i[-1])
        break
    i.append(int(y))
```

Can not take unknown amount in `f.sum(args)` part

Given `2,3,5`

Expected: `10`

Result: `5`

With `i[0], i[1]`

Comment: What is `f`, and where is it defined? And anyhow, if you are sending the function only `(i[0],i[-1])`, of course it will sum only those two items. Send it `i`.

Comment: You are passing the first (`i[0]`) and last (`i[-1]`) element, you have to pass i (`f.sum(i)`)

Comment: You are confusing two tasks: inputing numbers to a collection, and taking the sum. Programming is best when split into distinct tasks.

Comment: Also, it doesn't make sense to check if ´a is "q"´ (should be ´a ==q´) because you are converting them to ints before passing them.

Answer (score 1):

I think your main problem resides in what you are passing to the function. You are sending the first and last element, but (I think) you want to send the list:

```py
while True:
    i = []
    print("sum")
    y = int(input("Number: "))
    if y == 0:
        print(i)
        print_sum(i)
        break
    i.append(y)
```

Also, it doesn't make sense to check in the sum if a value "q", because you are assuming (when you add) they are integers:

```py
# Renamed to "print_sum", since I would expect "sum" to return it, and not print it
def print_sum(*args):
    total=0
    for a in args:
        total+=a
    print(total)
```

*Note:* I wrote this in the comments initally, but I thought it would be clearer in a comment.

**Edit:** Do you have to implement your own sum? [Python already has one](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum)

Comment: Please change `if y is 0` to `if y == 0`. `is` might work but it isn't guaranteed. Only use `is` if you really need object identity.

Comment: True, I didn't see it when I copied it